# How to make a POST request with json content type with Semantic UI API

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using the [API feature](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html) of dropdowns with Semantic UI and want to do a POST request on my API to search for users

By default the API feature of Semantic UI sends form-data content type.

To force the right content-type, I did something like :

```
receiverDropdown
    .dropdown({
        apiSettings: {
            url: '/api/search/',
            method: 'POST',
            beforeXHR: (xhr) => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            },
            beforeSend: (settings) => {
                settings.data = {
                    type: 'user',
                    query: 'test'
                }
                return settings
            }
        }
    })
```

but data is still sent in a form-data fashion, like `type=user&query=test` instead of a real JSON object payload like `{type: 'user', query: 'test'}`

How can I send a json object with Semantic UI API to my own POST API route ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify({type: 'user', query: 'test'})
```

Comment: Hi can you expand on this answer? Where in the `API` does this piece of code go?

Comment: I tried with this

`beforeSend: function(settings) {
    JSON.stringify(settings.data);
    return settings;
}`

This still posted to the server in the form `type=user&query=test`

Comment: settings.data = JSON.stringify({type: 'user', query: 'test'});
also, i have to add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",